# Magento 2 How to get selected Shipping address Pincode in onepage.phtml

Tags: magento2.3, cart, shipping-address

Here am trying to get the selected shipping address's pincode. But by object manager am getting first shipping addess but not the selected one.

[image]

this is my phtml file

`/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/MyVendor/theme-web/Magento_Checkout/templates/onepage.phtml`

```
<?php
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/PRAVone.log'); 
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger(); $logger->addWriter($writer); 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$shi=$cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();;
$logger->info($shi); 
?>
```

Where am doing wrong. Can I get Help? Thank you in advance

Comment: i think you are try `checkoutSession` meas that `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` and second your code double semi-columns https://prnt.sc/t1n4wo

Comment: Thank You @Mohit Patel for replying, I added session in the code. but still it showing the first address only. `$cart2 = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');

$shi=$cart2->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();`